# How to Join tables in SQL with SUM Function and Group?

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-server-2014

I'm creating a report to display project wise cost and revenue. I need to group  sum of A/P invoices and Sum of A/R invoices according to the project.

Same project could have many A/P invoices and A/R invoices which can include same Items.If there have 5 A/P invoices with same Items Like A,B,C I need to take Item wise sum of the amount also(Line wise Total sum)

All projects names and code(PrjCode-Primary Key) based in a separate table of OPRJ
Other Tables Structure as follows
A/P Invoice - OPCH(Main details) Link with PCH1(Item Details)
  On Primary Key - DocEntry
  PCH1 Lines Link with OPRJ on PCH1.Project = OPRJ.PrjCode

A/R Invoice - OINV(Main details) Link with INV1(Item Details)
  On Primary Key - DocEntry
  INV1 Lines Link with OPRJ on INV1.Project = OPRJ.PrjCode

I tries this query but couldn't get sum

```
select a.PrjCode,a.PrjName,b.ItemCode,sum(b.LineTotal),Sum(c.DocTotal),sum(e.DocTotal)
from OPRJ a 
Left Join PCH1 b on b.Project = a.PrjCode
Left Join OPCH c on c.DocEntry = b.DocEntry
Left Join INV1 d on d.Project = a.PrjCode and b.Project = d.Project
Left Join OINV e on e.DocEntry = d.DocEntry
Group by 
a.PrjCode,a.PrjName,c.DocTotal,e.DocTotal,b.ItemCode,b.LineTotal
```

Output what I expect is as follows

[image]

Sql Output without sum

[image]

Comment: Sample data will greatly help here. Also, that expected result appear to have no relevance to your SQL, so we need to see your attempt and expected results that are also related. (Considering, however, that you appear to be summing a `varchar`, I assume that is the problem?)

Answer (score 0):

you should remove the values you're summing up from the group by:

```
select a.PrjCode,a.PrjName,b.ItemCode,sum(b.LineTotal),Sum(c.DocTotal),sum(e.DocTotal)
from OPRJ a 
Left Join PCH1 b on b.Project = a.PrjCode
Left Join OPCH c on c.DocEntry = b.DocEntry
Left Join INV1 d on d.Project = a.PrjCode and b.Project = d.Project
Left Join OINV e on e.DocEntry = d.DocEntry
Group by 
a.PrjCode,a.PrjName,b.ItemCode
```

Comment: Hi, I need to get sum of line total if their have more than one item.How can I do that? Because i need to calculate cost per project

Comment: You can get that by using same statement as above, but remove `b.ItemCode` from the `select` clause **and** from the `group by` clause. This can be either as a separate SQL statement or as a subquery. You could add in `having count(b.ItemCode)>1` at the end, to only show the ones that are more than one item.